# zip longest lists and align output. python itertools from scratch

Tags: python, csv, zip, python-itertools

I am trying to compare one list to many lists and generate a csv file with values aligned.
itertools.zip_longest does a good job but because f the need to align the output, I thought I'd construct my own version. This would help be understand generators. If there is a better approach, please let me know.

Because the first list is the one I am comparing the rest of the lists to, I thought I would use args[0] to iterate over it and compare the others to it.
Because I wanted to manually run next(it) only once its value has been found, I created a cache to compare to.
I believe this is where I am having an issue.
I should be creating more rows that my results are showing.

```
def main():
    a = ['apple','banana','pear']
    b = ['apple','orange','orange','pear']
    c = ['banana','cucumber']
    d = ['1 apple','2 cherries']
    
    zipped_data = [','.join(x) for x in zip_longest_list(a,b,c,d,)]


def zip_longest_list(*args, fillvalue=''):
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    num_active = len(iterators)
    # I created a cache to compare lists with
    cache = [{'value': '', 'isLoaded': False} for i in range(num_active)]
    data = []
    # check if args are valid
    if not num_active:
        return

    # Because the first list is the one I am comparing the rest of the lists to
    # I thought I would use args[0] to iterate over it and compare the others to it

    # iterate over the list to compare to
    for i in args[0]:
        values = []

        for j, it in enumerate(iterators):
            value = ''

    # Because I wanted to manualy run next(it) only once its value has been found  
    # I created a cache

            # load cache
            try:
                if cache[i]['isLoaded'] == False:
                    value = next(it)
                    cache['value'] = value
                    cache[i]['isLoaded'] = True

            # check if list is empty
            except StopIteration:
                num_active -= 1
                if not num_active:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue

    # I believe this is where I am having an issue
    # I should be creating more rows that my results are showing

            if cache[i]['isLoaded'] == True:
                if i == cache[i]['value']:
                    new_row = []
                    [new_row.append(x['value']) for x in cache]
                    row.append(str(','.join([x for x in new_row])))
                    cache[i]['isLoaded'] = False
                else:
                    continue
        data.append(values)
    for i in data:
        yield i


# local copy of itertools.repeat
def repeat(object, times=None):
    if times is None:
        while True:
            yield object
    else:
        for i in range(times):
            yield object


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

expected output

```
[',,,1 apple']
[',,,2 cherries']
['apple,apple,,']
['banana,,banana,']
[',,cucumber,']
[',orange,,']
[',orange,,']
['pear,pear,,']
```

actual output

```
['apple,,,','apple,apple,,']
['banana,apple,banana,1 apple','banana,orange,banana,1 apple']
['pear,orange,banana,1 apple']
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have figured out how you get your desired output.  It looks like the old "file match" processes that were used to sort on magnetic tapes:

```
def fileMatch(*content, fillValue=None):
    Done      = []
    iterators = [ iter(c) for c in content ]
    values    = [ next(i,Done) for i in iterators ]
    while not all(v is Done for v in values):
        matchValue = min(v for v in values if v is not Done)
        matched    = [ v is not Done and v == matchValue for v in values ]
        yield  tuple ( v if isMatch else fillValue
                       for v,isMatch in zip(values,matched) )
        values     = [ next(i,Done) if isMatch else v
                       for v,isMatch,i in zip(values,matched,iterators) ]

for t in fileMatch(a,b,c,d,fillValue=""): print(t)

('', '', '', '1 apple')
('', '', '', '2 cherries')
('apple', 'apple', '', '')
('banana', '', 'banana', '')
('', '', 'cucumber', '')
('', 'orange', '', '')
('', 'orange', '', '')
('pear', 'pear', '', '')
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent a lot of time working on this one. Much appreciated!

Comment: In the end, re-testing for matches didn't feel efficient, I cleaned up the code so that the matching is only performed once and retained as flags in a matched list.

Answer (score 1):

A few more solutions...

My original:

```
def zip_longest_list(*args, fillvalue=''):
    its = list(map(iter, args))
    dummy = object()
    front = [next(it, dummy) for it in its]
    while not all(x is dummy for x in front):
        x = min(x for x in front if x is not dummy)
        result = []
        for i, y in enumerate(front):
            if y is not dummy and y == x:
                result.append(y)
                front[i] = next(its[i], dummy)
            else:
                result.append(fillvalue)
        yield tuple(result)
```

Trying to be short:

```
def zip_longest_list(*args, fillvalue=''):
    args = [a[::-1] for a in args]
    while any(args):
        x = min(a[-1] for a in args if a)
        yield tuple(a.pop() if x in a[-1:] else fillvalue for a in args)
```

Using `heapq.merge` trying to be efficient for finding the min (but then realized we're spending O(len(args)) for every yielded tuple anyway):

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

def zip_longest_list(*args, fillvalue=''):
    def gen(i, a):
        for k, g in groupby(a):
            for j, v in enumerate(g):
                yield v, j, i
    merged = merge(*(gen(*e) for e in enumerate(args)))
    for (v, _), g in groupby(merged, lambda t: t[:2]):
        s = {t[2] for t in g}
        yield tuple(v if i in s else fillvalue
                    for i in range(len(args)))
```

Using peekable iterators:

```
from more_itertools import peekable

def zip_longest_list(*args, fillvalue=''):
    its = list(map(peekable, args))
    while any(its):
        x = min(it.peek() for it in its if it)
        yield tuple(next(it) if it and it.peek() == x else fillvalue
                    for it in its)
```